# Update multiple oval coordinates on canvas in python using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am working on a gui to animate coin flips one at a time continuously.
I have two classes cointoss.py and flipbell.py.

Cointoss class generates the value change for coins and flipbell is used to animate the process.

As if now I have the code working to animate one coin at a time but not all the coins at a time.

When I say all coins this is the logic: first one coin comes down according to the value change, next another one comes down but the first coin value also gets updated accordingly and so on.

I need help how to move forward with what I have tried so far. I have used for loops to animate the process and I was thinking of using recursive method to have the logic part.

Any help with existing code or ideas to move forward would be great.

flipbell.py

```
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, Button, W, E
import random
from math import pi, sin, cos
from cointoss import *


class FlipBell(object):
    """
    GUI to simulate cointoss.
    """
    def __init__(self, wdw, dimension, increment, delay):
        """
        Determines the layout of the GUI.
        wdw : top level widget, the main window,
        dimension : determines the size of the canvas,
        increment : step size for a billiard move,
        delay : time between updates of canvas.
        """
        wdw.title('Coin flips and Bell Curve')
        self.dim = dimension # dimension of the canvas
        self.inc = increment
        self.dly = delay
        self.togo = False # state of animation
        # initial coordinates of the ball
        self.xpt = self.dim/2
        self.ypt = 0
        self.cnv = Canvas(wdw, width=self.dim,\
            height=self.dim, bg='white')
        self.cnv.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)
        self.bt0 = Button(wdw, text='start',\
            command=self.start)
        self.bt0.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W+E)
        self.bt1 = Button(wdw, text='stop',\
            command=self.stop)
        self.bt1.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W+E)

    def map2table(self, pnt):
        """
        Keeps the ball on the canvas table.
        """
        if pnt < 0:
            (quo, rest) = divmod(-pnt, self.dim)
        else:
            (quo, rest) = divmod(pnt, self.dim)
        return rest

    def placecoin(self, xpt, ypt):
        self.cnv.create_oval(xpt-1, ypt-1, xpt+1, ypt+1,\
            width=2, outline='red', fill='red', tags='coin')

    def drawball(self):
        """
        Draws the ball on the canvas.
        """
        xpt = self.map2table(self.xpt)
        ypt = self.map2table(self.ypt)
        self.cnv.delete('dot')
        self.cnv.create_oval(xpt-1, ypt-1, xpt+1, ypt+1,\
            width=1, outline='black', fill='red', tags='dot')

    def animate(self):
        """
        Performs the animation.
        """
        self.drawball()
        val = []
        for k in range(400):
            val1 = CoinToss.cointoss(3,k,self.dim//2)
            val.append(val1)

        points = {}
        for i in range(1,401):
            points[i] = 0
        for i in range(0,400):
            for j in range(0,400):
                (xpt, ypt) = (self.xpt, self.ypt)
                self.xpt = val[i][1][j]
                # print("x %d",self.xpt)
                self.ypt = ypt + 1
                # print("y %d",self.ypt)
                self.cnv.after(self.dly)
                self.drawball()
                self.cnv.update()

                #Puts the coin on top each other
                if self.ypt == 400:
                    if points[self.xpt]>=1:
                        self.placecoin(val[i][1][-1],400-points[self.xpt])
                    else:
                        self.placecoin(val[i][1][-1],400)
                    points[self.xpt]+=3
                    self.ypt = 0

    def start(self):
        """
        Starts the animation.
        """
        self.togo = True
        self.animate()

    def stop(self):
        """
        Stops the animation.
        """
        self.togo = False

def main():
    """
    Defines the dimensions of the canvas
    and launches the main event loop.
    """
    top = Tk()
    dimension = 400 # dimension of canvas
    increment = 10  # increment for coordinates
    delay = 1      # how much sleep before update
    num_flips = 3
    num_value = dimension//2
    FlipBell(top, dimension, increment, delay)
    top.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

cointoss.py

```
from random import randint
import random


class CoinToss:
    coin = 0
    def __init__(self, value,num_flip):
        # self.id = 1
        self.v = value
        self.state = 1
        self.flip = num_flip
        CoinToss.coin += 1


    def cointoss(self,coin,value):
        print('The ball at the start: ball: %d, state: %d, value: %d' % (coin, self, value))
        value_change = value
        coin_change = []
        for i in range(1,400+1):
            value = value_change
            value_change = CoinToss.flip(value)
            print('after flip %d, ball: %d, state: %d, value: %d' % (i,coin, i, value_change))
            coin_change.append(value_change)
        return([coin,coin_change])


    def flip(self):
        rand_value = randint(0, 1)
        if rand_value == 1:
            self +=1
        else:
            self -=1
        return self
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have named both a function and a variable "flip" in CoinToss which is confusing.  Also, you use the "tags" keyword and it should be "tag".  There is more than one way to code this.  The code below is not a complete solution but a simple example that shows how to use the CoinToss class to create and move an individual ball (doesn't check for move off of canvas).  The FlipBell class stores each CoinToss instance in a list and calls the "flip" function for each class each time a ball is created.  You could also use "after" within the CoinToss class to have the flip function call itself repeatedly.

```
from tkinter import *
from random import randint

class FlipBell(object):
    """
    GUI to simulate cointoss.
    """
    def __init__(self, wdw, dimension, delay):
        """
        Determines the layout of the GUI.
        wdw : top level widget, the main window,
        dimension : determines the size of the canvas,
        increment : step size for a billiard move,
        delay : time between updates of canvas.
        """
        wdw.title('Coin flips and Bell Curve')
        self.cnv = Canvas(wdw, width=dimension,
                          height=dimension, bg='white')
        self.cnv.grid()

        self.ct_instances=[]
        self.colors=["blue", "red", "yellow", "gray", "green"]
        self.delay=delay
        self.offset=0
        self.create_next()

    def create_next(self):
        """ create one ball for each color in self.colors
            and call each existing ball's flip function to
            move it a random amount
        """
        x=5
        y=5
        incr=10*self.offset
        CT=CoinToss(self.cnv, x+incr, y+incr, self.colors[self.offset])
        ##save each CoinToss (ball) instance in a list
        self.ct_instances.append(CT)
        self.offset += 1

        ## call flip (move ball) for each instance
        for instance in self.ct_instances:
            instance.flip()

        if self.offset < len(self.colors):
            self.cnv.after(self.delay, self.create_next)

class CoinToss:
    def __init__(self, canvas, start_x, start_y, color):
        self.cnv=canvas
        self.cointoss(start_x, start_y, color)


    def cointoss(self, start_x, start_y, color):
        self.this_ball=self.cnv.create_oval(start_x-5, start_y-5, start_x+5, start_y+5,
                       outline='black', fill=color, tag="dot")

    def flip(self):
        """ move the ball created for this class instance by a random amount
        """
        rand_value = randint(10, 50)
        self.cnv.move(self.this_ball, rand_value, rand_value)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    top = Tk()
    dimension = 400 # dimension of canvas
    delay = 500     # how much sleep before update --> 1/2 second
    num_flips = 3
    FP=FlipBell(top, dimension, delay)
    top.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. It helped me to figure out another way to do it.